# AWS-EB Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am first time trying to deploy my code using elastic bean stalk . I have created a small node webservice which is working fine on local but when I deploy that code in Elastic beanstalk i am getting below error.
I am completly new in AWS.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Require stack:
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: - /var/app/current/app.js
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/app.js:1:15)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/app.js' ]
Aug 13 06:36:49 ip-172-31-94-42 web: }
Aug 13 06:36:50 ip-172-31-94-42 web: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
Aug 13 06:36:50 ip-172-31-94-42 web: throw err;
Aug 13 06:36:50 ip-172-31-94-42 web: ^
Aug 13 06:36:50 ip-172-31-94-42 web: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

Comment: Have you installed `express` on EB?

Comment: no..let me check how i can do that

Comment: Have you fallowed [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html) on using express applications with EB?

Comment: I followed how can i upload node app,i am using codepipeline and git ..

Comment: do i need to create another application ?

Comment: can you post your app.js if you still having this issue

Comment: @NibhaJain By any chance do you remember how did you solve this issue?